# Android Intent is null in AlarmService

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting `Intent` object as null in Service `onStart()`.
Here is my `BroadCastReciever` class which calls the Service with `Intent`.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
   Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
   service1.putExtra("UNIQUE", intent.getExtras().getInt("UNIQUE"));
   service1.putExtra("UNIQUEMsg", intent.getExtras().getString("UNIQUEMsg"));
   service1.setAction(Intent.)
   context.startService(service1);       
}}
```

And here is my `MyAlarmService` where i am getting `Intent` response as null.

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    **NOTIFY_ME_ID = intent.getExtras().getInt("UNIQUE");**
    alarmtexttoprint = intent.getExtras().getString("UNIQUEMsg");
    ....
}
```

At this line:  `intent`.`getExtras()` ,I am getting `null pointer exception.`
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use :

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {}
```

Also you should use :

```
intent.getIntExtra("UNIQUE");
```

Comment: Still couldn't identify what could be reason for getting it null. However I am now using intent.getIntExtra() method. Possibly my Extras were null.